# Should I save my rabbi or my father?

Tags: kibbud-av-veim-honoring, honoring-rabbis

In massechet Kidushim, does it state that if a person has to choose between saving the life of his father or of his rabbi, he should save the rabbi?

Comment: You may be thinking of Bava Metzia 33a

Comment: I do know there is, I believe a Rambam, that if there is a child and a talmid chacham drowning, one should save the talmid chacham. I believe this is generally the approach of halacha.

Comment: There is a similar gemara as well in Horios (13a). If someone is in captivity with his father and his rebbe, his own release is of the highest priority, then his rebbe, then his father. And his mother takes precedence over all of them.  Although it may very well be that this gemara's halacha is not for the same reason as the gemara in Bava Metzia, becuase here the gemara seems to give precedence based on ability to replace a loss, not because of intrinsic value, see the continuation of the gemara.